# Is it possible to send real-time data to Azure Speaker Recognition API?

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, speech, mfcc, speaker

I am writing a voice-related project. I am developing a function to distinguish the voices of the people in the voices in real time.
I use the Microsoft Azure Speaker Recognition API to distinguish people's voices.

According to the API guide, I have to upload a WAV file to receive audio and Differentiate the users in the voice. 
However, I need to using real-time audio streams to distinguish users voice.

So my question is : how do I use a real-time audio stream to  implement Speaker Recognition?

1. Can I get real-time audio using Azure Speaker Recognition API, which requires only WAV files?
2. Or is there any other way than this API?

Comment: There are open source speaker identification toolkits like Kaldi, you can build streaming voice identification with them

Answer (score 2):

The current version of the APIs (1.0) doesn't support audio streaming, but this will be supported in version 2.0 which should be available in a few months (summer 2020).